# Application deployment failed when connecting with the database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have just finished the development of my application on asp.net mvc connected with SQL server, and I will love to deploy it. I want to use Azure App service, but I got an error "Unable to connect to master or target server 'DATABASE_NAME'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'DATABASE_NAME'". I have tried every thing I found online like modifying the SSDT, but nothing changed.

Please is there any recommendation to fix this issue? If not, Please what are other ways for me to launch the application. The application will be used internally for Sales purpose and I don't need any fancy hosting. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you setup the sql azure firewall to accept connections from your computer?
Even if you set it up once, it is possible that your internet provider attributed a different IP address to your computer. So you must redo your firewall set up again for your computer to be accepted.

[image]

It is important to know that only sql logins/passwords are accepted here. So you must give the login/password of the admin user that you mentioned at the moment of creation of you sql server azure (there is a step that sets it up when you create your azure database), or the login/password of a user you created and granted in this database.

Comment: I am making the publish from Visual Studio app. I make connection to the database during deployment by clicking on "Settings" in Visual Studio publish section

Comment: Sure, I understand, but still, you must make the proper setup on sql azure prior to deploy from visual studio. By default, sql azure database (I'm not talking about sql azure web portal here) only accepts connection from machine that are within azure, otherwise it would be very unsafe if any body in the world could try to connect your DB. This is why you must setup the firewall like mentioned on the picture to add your remote machine (it is a remote machine for azure) to connect to the server.

Comment: by the way, if your computers where there is the client application are not with a fix IP address, your architecture doesn't work unless you setup the firewall everytime a machine is given a new ip by the internet provider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But do I need to migrate my database from sql server to azure before the publish?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question... what do you mean by "migrate"? what exactly would you migrate? data or structure? Actually to deploy a database on azure, there are only two proper ways: the first, you have a web service accessing the database through a code first tool so during deployment you request entity framework to update the structure. The second , you managed the database structure with a database project. So during the deployment you VS or you admin to deploy the dacpac against you db; it will update the structure.